# how to store the replies(like comments in facebook and answers in quora) in android

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview

I got stuck in between.
I am new to android and i am making an application in which the user replies to the question.I want the reply to be there forever below the question.
can anyone suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Quite a broad question, but I would consider using the Volley library for Android to connect the app to the backend of your system([[Tutorial here]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzwBYPzCIHk)) and then SQLite to store data on the user's phone as well.

Answer (score 0):

To broad to answer but still one suggestion is that you should save comments or answers into remote server because saving in SQlite to users phone will eat too much memory of device.